# Amazon MQ: Using RabbitMQ with Stomp

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

Is there a way to configure Amazon MQs RabbitMQ to work with the Stomp protocol? I know you need a plugin for RabbitMQ to be able to use Stomp, but I can't find how I would install the plugin on the Amazon MQ instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible right now to have installed the stomp plugin.

When you provision a rabbit MQ broker with AmazonMQ, AWS will deploy for you a cluster that is fully managed by AWS so you do not have any access to the underline installation, therefore you do not have any possibility to configure and install another plugin. At the time that I wrote this answer the available plugin are Shovel, Federation, Consistent Hash exchange

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/rabbitmq-basic-elements-plugins.html

I would suggest to evaluate ActiveMQ, because it supports STOMP
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/broker.html